# Cannot get chrome.window instance with chrome.app.window.get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying the following code when i click on a button:

```
chrome.app.window.create('sample.html', {
        id: 'test',
        'bounds': {
          'width': 200,
          'height': 200
        },
        'resizable' : false,
        'frame': { type: "none" }
    })
    console.debug(chrome.app.window.getAll())
    var windowcreated = chrome.app.window.get('test');
    windowcreated.innerBounds.height = 50;
    windowcreated.innerBounds.width = 200;
```

But here's what the console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerBounds' of null

And the debug of getAll() only returns my original window created in background.js. I don't get what i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.app.window.create()` is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/934239).

By the time your execution reaches `chrome.app.window.get('test')`, that window does not exist yet.

You need to move your logic in the [callback of `chrome.app.window.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create):

```
chrome.app.window.create('sample.html', {
    id: 'test',
    'bounds': {
      'width': 200,
      'height': 200
    },
    'resizable' : false,
    'frame': { type: "none" }
}, function(createdWindow) {
  // Do stuff here, and no need for get()
  createdWindow.innerBounds.height = 50;
  createdWindow.innerBounds.width = 200;
});
```

Comment: Thanks man ! I will do that :) Didn't know it was asynchronous.

Comment: Most of the Chrome API is asynchronous. Exceptions (like `get()` here) are rare.